# how to call a COBOL program through shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, cobol

I have a requirement like execute/call a COBOL program through shell script. i should pass the input parameters (for COBOL'S ACCEPT statements) with the help of here document from the shell script.

Can any one suggest me how can i invoke a COBOL program through shell script.

Comment: You really should include in your question how one does in general execute COBOL programs in your environment as your question seems to include a hidden assumption of not using GNU Compiler Collection COBOL compiler (consult a search engine or see http://cobolforgcc.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: You have already asked and abandoned this question in a slightly different form. Why do you expect answers if you don't respond or give feedback? Fourth one on the Related to the right.

Comment: @BillWoodger..  i just wanted to know possible ways to call to COBOL program thru shell script..

Comment: Fair enough, but it even looks possible that all your questions relate to this. People have supplied answers, but have no clue whether they were any use to you.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using AcuCobol then try below:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /path/to/runcbl $PROGRAM
```

Comment: My COBOL is micro focus COBOL.. and shell script should be able to pass the COBOL's ACCEPT statments (input params) by using here document.